# How to perform distinct while having multiple paths using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For a given node(sourceNode) I want to retrieve all node's which has relationships to my sourceNode within 3 hops.

The problem starts when we have multiple pathes btw source and destination nodes.

I dont care which path I get as long as I get one and I dont want to get the other ones (would be great to get only the **shortest** path)

So this is my code:

```
MATCH (user:C9 {userId:'70'})-[r:follow*1..3]-f WHERE f <> user 
RETURN DISTINCT (f.userId) as userId, 
reduce(s = '', rel IN r | s + rel.dist + ',') as dist,
length(r) as hop
```

The repose for this consist the same nodeId(userId's) and not performing distinct:

[image: result from neo4j]

I would like to avoid the duplicated lines with the same userId.

any idea how to perform the distinct here?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? Rather than look for distinct user just ue *shortestPath* to get to each follower 1..3 out from the starting user.

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((user:C9 {userId:'70'})-[r:follow*1..3]-(f)) 
WHERE f <> user 
RETURN f.userId, 
reduce(s = '', rel IN r | s + rel.dist + ',') as dist,
length(p) as hop
```

Alternatively, if you were looking to do it by shortest distance regardless of hops you could do something like the following example.  Instead of using shortestPath, aggregate the distances on each relationship, order by shortest, put them in a collection, order by user and return the first element of the collection which will be the shortest

```
MATCH p=(user:C9 {userId:'70'})-[r:follow*1..3]-(f)
WHERE f <> user 
with f.userId as user_id
, reduce(s = 0, rel IN relationships(p) | s + rel.dist) as dist
, length(p) as hops
order by dist
with user_id, collect(dist) as dists_per_follow, collect(hops) as hops_per_follow
return user_id
, dists_per_follow[0] as shortest
, dists_per_follow, hops_per_follow
order by user_id
```

Comment: What about performances? how heavy would that be having this query running simultaneously

Comment: That is a pretty wide opened question. Simultaneously with what? The actual answer is going to depend a lot on the size of your database, the number of these paths, the number of nodes with those labels, frequency of execution, etc.  The second query is generally going to be more expensive than the first because you will generally return more paths (i.e. more database hits) in the second one as you are returning all paths and doing some post processing versus just the shortest path.  You could improve the queries themselves instantly by adding a label to (f) in the path (i.e. `f:C9`).